# Is there a VNC client that supports the default encryption used by vino

Tags: 18.04, vnc, vino

I am looking for a VNC Client for Mac (also interesting for Windows) that supports the default encryption of Vino.

All the posts I find just show how to disable the encryption requirement (that is not really the idea of it, right?)
I tried several VNC clients for Mac, the integrated one, Real, Tight, Tiger, ... they all don't support the encryption from the Default Desktop Sharing of Ubuntu.

Does anyone know a client which supports it?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd love one for Android as well.

Comment: I haven't found one yet either.

Comment: Facing the exact same problem, any news since June?

Comment: Unfortunate that the question has been closed. While Florian is asking about encryption on Mac particularly, this is a problem with VNC clients generally when using a non-Linux OS (Windows, Mac).

Answer (score 2):

Not yet verified:
The enhanced TightVNC viewer should be able to do it.
http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html

More details to this issue can be found here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250

There was also a hint for android users.

Comment: caution for anyone who downloads ssvnc - Windows detected a trojan in the .zip file